# Can someone help me understand this transistor circuit?

Tags: audio, phase-shift

[image]

I believe the purpose of this circuit is to perform SQ decoding. It is supposed to shift the phase 90° from 100 Hz to 10 kHz.

I'm interested in listening to the quad version of the Pink Floyd Animals LP. I came across a bigger circuit, in a 70s electronics magazine, of which this network is a part.

My goal is to make this circuit, but I would also like to understand the phase shifting network.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is it supposed to produce the shifted phase? I assume across R4, but you haven't mentioned it. Also, PLEASE redo your drawing to put V1 to the left of V2, so we don't have to guess whether or not the ground connection includes V2 and C3.

Comment: Also, that's not going to work as given. With V2 at 20 V RMS, that will be about 56 Vpk-pk. Running that into a 25 volt amp will severely clip the signal, and I don't like to think what that will do to the subsequent RC networks.

Comment: Sorry, I got the print before the last changing ion the circuit. This is the final version.

Comment: First off, I'm new to this forum, so, sorry for my mistakes, and I don't know how to post another picture.

Comment: And, yes, V2 is across R4.

Comment: And in fact, simulation shows that at 1 kHz the output is a not-remotely-sinusoidal waveform almost exactly 180 degrees out of phase. And a 4 v pk-pk input gives about 3 v pk-pk, again at 180 degrees.

Comment: It is supposed to be fed from either the left or right side of a record needle, which is definitely not a pure sine waveform.

Comment: Your edit made the clipping far worse. No record needle will ever produce 500Vrms! Did you mean 500mVrms, perhaps?

Comment: A record needle does not put out 20 volts rms.

Comment: No, it doesn't, sorry again, it's 500mV.

Comment: To be clear, what exactly is this circuit supposed to do?  At first I thought you were just looking to play 2 2 channel stereo tracks simultaneously, but it appears that you are instead using this circuit to simulate the second 2 channels?  90 degrees phase shift across a range of frequencies should just give you an echo/distortion/clipping effect I think.  Is this the intent, or is there some sort of hidden signal you're trying to unlock?

Comment: Yep, that's the thing, few records, of which the Pink Floyd Animals is among them, have 4 channels encoded into 2 channels, and such circuit is part of a decoder.

Comment: It's called SQ decoding.

Comment: So, the short answer is that nobody can tell you how to make the circuit work, because it doesn't. It's basically a high-pass filter with a corner frequency of about 1 kHz. Phase varies about 400 degrees across the region from about 10 Hz to 10 kHz. Unless that's what you want it do, of course.

Comment: Also the Darkside of the Moon.

Comment: Ah found it.  You should edit your post as the other folk are requesting, and also include a line to the effect of "I believe the purpose of this circuit is to perform SQ decoding."  It's a cool project and I hope it works for you, but if you haven't bought the album yet I'd consider going straight to the 5.1 channel SACD =).

Comment: I do have the Animals, the Darkside of the Moon, a couple Rick Wakeman's, and a few other quad albums.

Comment: So, it won't work? I got the circuit from an issue of Wireless World magazine. https://www.americanradiohistory.com/Archive-Wireless-World/70s/Wireless-World-1973-03.pdf

Comment: Ah.   The albums should be labelled for the specific SQ encoding used (eg. 4-2-4) so you don't end up using a circuit for the wrong one.  The other guys around here like WhatRoughBeast can figure out this kind of circuit with just a look, but it's a bit above my skill level.  For these questions, I usually just end up helping with small matters of clarity, so I can help you make your question shiny and identify missing information for you but that's about it.

Comment: They all are, as seen on the Darkside picture, not mine thou, but I can post a photo of my own with the SQ symbol on it when I get home.

Comment: And, tahnk you KH.

Comment: Easiest way to skin this these days is just to rip the thing into your PC, then use a hilbert transform to get the phase shift. Real analogue phase shift networks do exist but a reasonably stable 90 degrees over 3 decades of bandwidth is a big network of strange valued precision caps and resistors. Look in the ham radio literature for design examples from 'phasing' SSB sets for the basic method.

Comment: As for your circuit, you should think about the values of C1 and C2 at your frequencies of interest. 0.1 uF at 1 kHz is about 1.6 k, so its contribution to the current into R4 will swamp that of R3 for any frequency above about 100 Hz, which is the lower end of your desired frequency range.

Comment: @DaveTweed - I think you duplicated a paragraph when you edited the question.

Comment: @Bort: No, that's the OP's text. He posted followup information as an answer, and I just converted that to an edit of the question.

Comment: Many years ago I made an SQ decoder with the Motorola IC. But I have not played a record also for many years.

Comment: 40 or 45 years ago I made an SQ decoder using the Motorola ICs and it worked well, even with ordinary stereo. I haven't used it for 35 years.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit works as follows: @WhatRoughBeast is correct, the voltage must be low enough so that everything stays under the power supply voltage.  The input is level shifted with C3, R7, and R8 so that it is basically the same signal at the base except that it is centered about midway between V1 and ground.  Q1 emitter is basically a voltage follower one diode drop below this midpoint.  So the signal at Q1 is pretty much the same amplitude and phase as the input.  Because the gain (beta) of the transistor is high, we can say that the collector and emitter current is almost identical, so that the voltage on the collector is the same amplitude as the voltage on the emitter, but is 180 degrees out of phase.  So you have two voltage sources, one in phase and one out of phase, and they are connected to your load through different impedances.  You can do the math but intuitively you can see that as the frequencies change, the contributions from the two voltage sources also change so that the phase shift does not change as much with frequency as it would with a simple RC.  It does not provide a true constant phase shift.  If you want a constant 90-degree phase shift, you can do a much better job with a simple op amp circuit.  However, musician types looking for new sounds often experiment until they get what they want, especially in the era you mentioned when op amps were not available.

Comment: The very simple circuit will have barely any separation between the 4 channels. 42 years ago I made an SQ Full Logic circuit using Motorola MC1312 decoder, MC1314 voltage controlled attenuator and MC1315 logic ICs. Records recorded with SQ play with good channels separation and ordinary stereo plays with interesting channels levels changes.